# slide show images for iOS

Tags: ios, catransition

m file for slide view my pics and i have 8 of them but when run the program it will skip the no.1 pic and start from the 2 pic.how to do it right please

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{    
    [super viewDidLoad];   
    imageId=0;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(changeImage) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)changeImage
{
    imageId = imageId + 1;
    CATransition * trs = [CATransition animation];
    trs.duration = 1;
    [trs setType:kCATransitionPush];
    int id = imageId % NUMBER_OF_IMAGES;
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png", id]];
    [imageView.layer addAnimation:trs forKey:kCATransition];
}
```

Comment: You're incrementing imageId when changeImage method is called. You could either set imageId to -1 in viewDidLoad or increment imageId in the last line of your changeImage method. **Edit:** this assumes your images start with 0.png

Comment: none of them works :(

Answer (score 0):

As stated by [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/493385/chris) you are increment the image number when you are loading you images.
Just move the increment line to the end of you method:

```
-(void)changeImage {
//    imageId = imageId + 1;
    CATransition * trs = [CATransition animation];
    trs.duration = 1;
    [trs setType:kCATransitionPush];
    int id = imageId % NUMBER_OF_IMAGES;
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png", id]];
    [imageView.layer addAnimation:trs forKey:kCATransition];
    imageId++;
}
```

Comment: its kind of worked but the second pic is repeated twice until the third shown !! why ?